# Family Based Green card Application, From I-140 needed?

Tags: working-visas, greencard, family

I applied for a family based green card (concurrently filed I-130, I-485, I-131 and I-765), did I need to submit form I-140 as well?

Answer (score 1):

No. I-140 is the petition for employment-based immigration (analogous to I-130 which is the petition for family-based immigration).